# The YUI 'valuechange' event is not fired

Tags: javascript, yui

http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/cKWJh/

typing stuff into the text box in the aforementioned jsFiddle should open an alert window. It does not and I have no idea why.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait until after the TabView is rendered to listen to events on DOM nodes that live inside the TabView. This is because the setter for the `content` attribute of each Tab is executed when rendering and that setter does:

```
this.get('panelNode').setContent(content);
```

This rewrites the `innerHTML` of the panel node and so you lose all references to nodes and event listeners.

Here's a quick and dirty edit of your Fiddle to show how you can put your event initialization code in a function and call it after rendering the TabView: http://jsfiddle.net/vWb5R/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'event-valuechange' to your use() list.

Comment: It is there through the requirements of the gl-utils module.